# Jersey 404 error

Tags: jersey

Hi I am new to Rest API , by following videos I tried to execute a Jersey program. but getting error 404, Please educate me.
When I try to execute in Tomcat 07v as 
http://localhost:8080/rws/rest/messages
i got 404 error.

MyResource class:

```
package org.uv;
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/messages")
public class MyResource {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getMessages(){
        return "Hello World";
    }

}
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" 
version="3.0">
<display-name>rws</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
<servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
</servlet-class>
<init-param>
<param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
<param-value>org.uv</param-value>
</init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: jersey version ?

Comment: @Kalpa Jersey Version 2.1

Comment: You haven't specified how you resolve your dependencies. Can you confirm that all javax.servlet.* javax.ws.rs.* , jersey jars are present in the Web-Inf/lib and you have deployed the war on tomcat properly?

Comment: Try to remove the first star from the url-pattern "<REMOVE-THIS-STAR>/rest/*", leave only "/rest/*.

Comment: @Kalpa , i tried using Maven. I found some difficulties regarding build path(Jersey version), and JRE Environment, And i fix those, Now its working fine in Maven. Thanks alot guys...